# How to debug any sh file inside Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Echo statements are not printing in console when i build container.

I am able to see the information as below

```
Step 1/3 : FROM jboss/wildfly:latest
 b4680c565eae
Step 2/3 : ADD customization /opt/jboss/wildfly/customization/
 bc78405babec
Removing intermediate container 7b22667b3310
Step 3/3 : CMD /opt/jboss/wildfly/customization/execute.sh
 Running in 76f8bfe9ac95
5cb0fa9482f4
Removing intermediate container 76f8bfe9ac95
Successfully built 5cb0fa9482f4
Successfully tagged madhu/wildfly-mysql-javaee7:latest
```

execute.sh file includes echo statements, but not writing to console.

Would be interested to know, how we should be able to debug the script.

Comment: `CMD` is not executed at build time. It's executed at *runtime*. Thus, when it says "Running", all that's running is an edit to the metadata that controls how the image will behave when it's started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script specified in `CMD` is not executed at build time -- it's executed at runtime. You need to attempt a `docker run` to see its output.

If you want more output (and/or more *useful* output -- when used to show commands being executed, `echo` tends to throw away important details such as the difference between literal and syntactic spaces) your `echo`s provide, modify the `CMD` or the script to set the `-x` shell command. You can do this by putting `set -x` in your script (under the shebang), or amending the `CMD`, to something like: `CMD ['/bin/bash', '-x', '/opt/jboss/wildfly/customization/execute.sh']` (using `/bin/bash` if the shebang is `#!/bin/bash`, `/bin/sh` if the shebang is `/bin/sh`, etc).

Comment: "You can do this by putting set -x in your script (under the shebang)", this really save hours of debugging scripts running with `docker run ... -c script.sh`